# Printing Out a String Stored in an Array of DWORDS

Tags: arrays, string, assembly

I'm writing a program in Assembly that will Bubble Sort an Array of Strings. A zero length string terminates the array. I approached this by declaring a DWORD array, where the string var., that is a byte size, shall be stored. My main problem is not the bubble sort itself, but that strings that were stored in the array wasn't outputting completely.

To hopefully make it clear, here is my code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h   ; header file for input/output

space           equ     0
cr              equ     0dh

.STACK 4096

.DATA           
myStrings               byte    "Delts",0
                        byte    "Abs",0
                        byte    "Biceps",0
                        byte    0

labelStrOut             byte    "Output is: ", 0

stringOut               dword   11 dup (?)

stringNum               dword   0
stringArray             dword   20 dup (?)              


.CODE

_MainProc PROC  

            mov edi, offset myStrings
            mov esi, offset stringArray


 popltLp:       
            cmp BYTE PTR [edi], 0
            jz popltDone
            mov ebx, [edi]
            mov DWORD PTR [esi], ebx            
            add esi, 4
            inc stringNum
            xor ecx, ecx
            not ecx
            xor al, al
            repne scasb 
            jmp popltLp

popltDone: 
            xor edx, edx


            lea esi, stringArray
            mov ebx, DWORD PTR [esi]
            mov stringOut, ebx
            output labelStrOut, stringOut
            add esi, 4
            mov ebx, DWORD PTR [esi]
            mov stringOut, ebx
            output labelStrOut, stringOut   
            add esi, 4
            mov ebx, DWORD PTR [esi]
            mov stringOut, ebx
            output labelStrOut, stringOut


outptDone:

            mov  eax, 0                     ;     exit with return code 0
            ret
_MainProc ENDP


END                             ; end of source code
```

As can be seen, no Bubble Sorting is being done yet...

The lines below 'popltDone' is just me messing around to see if the strings carried over to the array just fine. However, when printed out on the screen, only 4 characters were just showing up! The entire string line was just not being printed out, which is currently driving me crazy. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks to anybody taking the time reading this.

Comment: Is this homework?  Can you add the output you see?

Comment: In the screen, output is pretty much: "Delt", "Abs", and "Bice" respectively. Always 4 characters... don't know why, must be using the wrong instructions to store strings into array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you aren't using string pointers correctly. Specifically, here's the code I'm referring to:

```
mov ebx, [edi]
mov DWORD PTR [esi], ebx
```

If you were to translate this into English, it would be something like this:

```
Move the 4 byte value pointed to by edi into ebx.
Move the value in ebx into the memory address pointed to by esi.
```

This is perfectly legal and may actually be what you want in some cases, but I'm guess this isn't one of them. The reason you are only seeing the first 4 characters when you output your array of strings is because you copied the literal string into your array. A DWORD is 4 bytes so you get the first 4 characters. Here's what I would write:

```
mov DWORD PTR [esi], edi
```

Which translates into:

```
Move the pointer value edi into the memory address pointed to by esi.
```

Now you have not an array of strings, but an array of string pointers. If you were to write your code in C, decompile it, this is most likely what you would see. Rewrite your comparison and output functions to work with the pointer to a string instead of the literal characters in the string and you'll fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Sparafusile. Though now I am faced with a new conundrum: when I output any of the elements inside the array of string pointers, all I get is blank!

    ;Below is the instruction I'm using
    ;to output it

Comment: **Argh, disregard my comment above... I'm still new to this site, and all of its kinks...

Thanks for your help, Sparafusile. Though now I am faced with a new conundrum: when I output any of the elements inside the array of string pointers, all I get is blank!

Below is the instruction I've been using to print it out:

    lea esi, stringArray
    output labelStrOut, DWORD PTR [esi]

As said, my output window is blank, currently figuring out a way to get around it.

Comment: You are trying to print the pointer to a pointer. Try this instead: "output labelStrOut, esi". To move to the next string, add 4 to esi.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. The instruction you recommended me to use, "output labelStrOut, esi", unfortunately gave me a compiler error. "Error A2070:invalid instruction operands"